# How to solve this firefox problem : Did not connect?

Tags: firefox

Good afternoon ,

Excuse me if this question doesn't meet the StackOverflow rules.

I have the following problem with firefox :

[image]

This probem vanishes when i run the **adwcleaner_8.3.0**. However , i get the same problem again when i restart my laptop.

Thank you for help !

Comment: Please put the question in the right forum , thank you in advance for help !

Comment: Could someone gives a suggestion